# Are every version of Bluestacks fully compatible with macOS Big Sur 11.0.1?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I upgraded to BigSur version 11.0.1 yesterday but after that, I am not able to open Bluestacks

Whenever I try so, it prompts that this [image]

I clicked on open system preferences, but there I don't get an option to allow it

[image]

After 3-5 minutes, it shows this

[image]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this now has been fixed! Try reinstalling Bluestacks newest version

https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360053434311-How-to-use-BlueStacks-on-MacOS-11-Big-Sur